# javascript 'short hand' notation in cycle plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this while going through some cycle plugin options:

```
$('#prev')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']()
```

I hate to admit but i'm having a hard time expanding this into it's 'long' form.
I know that if index is 0 element gets hidden otherwise it's visible.
It's the `$('#prev')[index == 0` that is tripping me up :-(

Comment: Of course, they could have gone with `$('#prev').toggle(index != 0);`. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that is not how the cool kids roll!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - tricky tricky! I don't think I'd actually put that in my prod code... but it's nice to know that's an option :P

Comment: @Lix: Why not? It's [documented](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide), shouldn't be going anywhere... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you would write either `$("#prev").hide()` or `$("#prev").show()` depending on what you want to do.

However, you can access properties on objects by using square brackets `[]` with the property name as a string - among other things, this allows for object keys that contain characters that wouldn't be valid otherwise. Even something like `obj["some property name"]` would be valid here.

So basically, what your ternary operator is doing is choosing whether to get the `show` or `hide` string, which is then used to retrieve that property of the jQuery object (in this case, the methods) and calling them.

Answer (score 3):

To make it simple for you, the code below:

```
$('#prev')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
```

is same as doing:

```
if (index == 0) {
    $('#prev').hide();
} else {
    $('#prev').show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All that's really happening here is a test on the index variable. If it is equal to zero then the element is being hidden, otherwise it is being shown:

```
var elem = $('#prev');
if ( index == 0 ) {
  elem.hide();
} else {
  elem.show();
}
```

The 'hide' and 'show' strings are merely the names of the functions. Which function needs to be called is decided by the ternary conditional statement. Both of those functions are functions of the element and therefor you call them on the actual element. The brackets at the end of the statement is what actually calls the function.